# Why can I access my Raspi via ftp (FileZilla) even after stopping the 'vsftpd' service?

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, raspberry-pi

I've been fiddling with my new RasPi 3 and one of the first things I did was to setup an FTP server to transfer files between my Pi and my laptop via the local Wifi network. I installed the 'vsftpd' package and started the service. Everything went smooth and I was able to access the files from a Windows machine using FileZilla. Then today after booting it up, I killed the service by issuing :

```
sudo service vsftpd stop
```

The command worked. I made sure that 'vsftpd' was not running by

```
sudo service --status-all | grep "vsftpd"
[ - ] vsftpd
```

But the weird thing is that I can still access the files by logging in using FileZilla.

```
Status: Connecting to propi...
Status: Connected to propi
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Listing directory /home/pi
Status: Directory listing of "/home/pi" successful
```

I'm new to linux and I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously some process is still running and providing FTP functionality. Have a look at which process uses the FTP port (Port 21) with `sudo netstat -tulpn`.

If vsftpd is still using it then have a look at the vsftpd log files. (the service command just runs a bash script which is supposed to stop the service - it could fail to do so)